# Can I run my mod_perl application as an ordinary user

Tags: perl, cgi, mod-perl, suexec

Can I run my mod_perl aplication as an ordinary user similar to running a plain vanilla CGI application under suexec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [source](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/install.html#Is_it_possible_to_run_mod_perl_enabled_Apache_as_suExec_):

> **Is it possible to run mod_perl enabled Apache as suExec?**
>
> The answer is No. The reason is that
>   you can't "suid" a part of a process.
>   mod_perl lives inside the Apache
>   process, so its UID and GID are the
>   same as the Apache process.
>
> You have to use mod_cgi if you need
>   this functionality.
>
> Another solution is to use a crontab
>   to call some script that will check
>   whether there is something to do and
>   will execute it. The mod_perl script
>   will be able to create and update this
>   todo list.

A more nuanced answer with some possible workarounds from ["Practical mod_perl" book](http://chestofbooks.com/computers/webservers/apache/Stas-Bekman/Practical-mod_perl/C-1-Users-Sharing-a-Single-Web-Server.html):
(I hope that's not a pirated content, if it is please edit it out)

> mod_perl 2.0 improves the situation,
>   since it allows a pool of Perl
>   interpreters to be dedicated to a
>   single virtual host. It is possible to
>   set the UIDs and GIDs of these
>   interpreters to be those of the user
>   for which the virtual host is
>   configured, so users can operate
>   within their own protected spaces and
>   are unable to interfere with other
>   users.

Additional solutions from the sme book are in [appendix C2](http://chestofbooks.com/computers/webservers/apache/Stas-Bekman/Practical-mod_perl/C-2-Users-Sharing-a-Single-Machine.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mod_perl runs within the apache process, I would think the answer is generally no.  You could, for example, run a separate apache process as this ordinary user and use the main apache process as a proxy for it.